# Why is my Powershell script checking if process is running giving error if it cannot find the process?

Tags: powershell

I have the following ps1 script:

```
 $process_check = Get-Service "Process" | findstr -i "Process" 
echo $process_check
```

When I execute it finds my process called "process" and gives the output

```
*output*
Running  Process        Process_displayName
```

I want to make sure my script gives me the expected output if "Process" is not running. To check this i created a new variable this time checking for process "QWERTY" so my full script is:

```
$process_check = Get-Service "Process" | findstr -i "Process" 
$qwerty_check = Get-Service "QWERTY" | findstr -i "QWERTY" 
echo $process_check
echo $qwerty_check
```

This outputs the following:

```
*output*
Running  Process        Process_displayName

Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'qwerty'.
At C:\Users\proc_checks.ps1:5 char:14
+ $qwerty_check = Get-Service "qwerty" | findstr -i "qwerty"
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qwerty:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Is there a way I can have the script not error if it cant find the process by my set process name (in this case "Process" and "qwerty")

Do I perhaps need an if statment checking for null before I assign my variables?

Comment: Any suggestion on how to improve my skills are welcomed. However in future please reframe from dictating/telling/suggesting what i should do without any practical resource to complete your suggestion and instead suggest practical resources i can use to achieve your recommendation. e.g. "I strongly recommend you read the following tutorial"

Comment: A recommendation is hardly "dictating" something, so don't get your panties in a bunch.

Comment: Thats hardly helpful now is it. I am simply requesting that if you are going to tell me something i should be doing, then a practical resource or example of how to achieve what you are suggesting is far more effective. Much like how this site suggestions you ask good questions but providing examples of what you are doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201103/discussion-between-a-smith-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scepticalist has what I would use- your reply seems to indicate you're not familiar with a try/catch block. You can search on "try catch block" or "exception handling" to learn more.

Simply put- Scepticalist's code tries to execute the process check. If everything goes well, the code inside the catch never executes. However, if there is an error, the code inside the catch "catches" that error and tries to do something about it. There's also an optional "Finally" that will always run- regardless of errors.

So if you want that data in a variable- assign it to that variable in the catch block.

```
# Name of the process to check for
$ProcessRequest = 'OUTLOOK'

# Check for process by name
Try {
    $Process_Check = Get-Process -Name $ProcessRequest -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "This line of code will not execute if the process check fails- execution immediately jumps to the catch"
}
Catch {
    #This code only executes if the code in try encounters an error
    $Process_Check = "Process not found for $ProcessRequest`nError: $_"
    Write-Host $Process_Check
}
Finally
{
    Write-Host "This code always runs, regardless of errors"
}

# The result of the query is now held in the $Process_Check object
# Output the object - you can pick any fields you need rather than *

$Process_Check | Select *
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, thats a really clear explanation. No i am not familiar with try catch block and as has been pointed out by others i lack much knowledge of how powershell works but answers like yours go much further to helping my development compared to comments akin to: go figure it out elsewhere. 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As you play around, check out $_ in the catch block. $_ in PowerShell refers to the current object in a pipeline, so inside this catch it refers to the error being thrown.

For example, if you weren't sure what caused the error, $_.ScriptStackTrace might be useful data to output for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Process` errors out by design if it doesn't find anything. To change that behavior you can use the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` parameter.

```
$process_check = Get-Service "Process" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | findstr -i "Process" 
echo $process_check
```

Note that `-ErrorAction` is a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6) and will work on any cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks, while this stops the error it means my variable will get no value. Would the best way to set a value if it get-service errors be to use an if?

Comment: `Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Process' }` or `Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Process*' }` would be a better approach than suppressing errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The question from my comment above is the same with @dee-see method or your method?

Comment: What value do you expect exactly when the process isn't running?

Answer (score 0):

As Ansgar suggests, go and learn how to use Powershell, because mixing it with command line/batch is never going to make your scripting robust or efficient.

```
# Name of the process to check for
$ProcessRequest = 'OUTLOOK'

# Check for process by name
Try {
    $Process_Check = Get-Process -Name $ProcessRequest -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Process not found for $ProcessRequest`nError: $_"
}

# The result of the query is now held in the $Process_Check object
# Output the object - you can pick any fields you need rather than *

$Process_Check | Select *
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions for useful tutorials?
In regards to your answer, it gives me an output rather then an error if the process is not running but i need this output to be callable in a variable but trying to echo or trying to run your suggestions of "$Process_Check | select *" gives no output at all?

Comment: Then instead of Write-Host, output the Catch to a variable such as $NoProcess. Really, this is simple stuff.

Comment: Thanks thats what i needed. I appreciate this may be simple stuff to someone experienced in this, i am just trying to learn and improve myself and i have as yet been unable to find a resource that helps me in this quest as well as Stackoverflow. You may do well to remember what is simple to you may-not be simple to others and likewise what is simple to others may not be simple to you, this will stand you in good stead when the times comes for you to ask a question that someone else can answer with ease :)